# Load symmetric matrix into pandas DataFrame where file has 3-column format (row, column, data)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a symmetric matrix stored in a tab-separated file that has 3 columns, where the first two columns are the row and column position and the third column is the data. And because it's a symmetric matrix only one triangle is represented, so it looks something like this:

```
A A 0.2
A B 0.1
B B 1.2
A C 0.9
B C 2.3
C C 3.4
A D 2.1
B D 4.3
C D 0.8
D D 1.0
...
```

Are there any convenience functions that make it easy to load this into a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Load it in what way? I'm not sure what you're expecting the convenience method to do for you. Just load it as a CSV and specify the delimiter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=['row', 'col', 'val'], sep=' ')

# A A 0.2
# A B 0.1
# B B 1.2
# A C 0.9
# B C 2.3
# C C 3.4
# A D 2.1
# B D 4.3
# C D 0.8
# D D 1.0
```

You can use the [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function to create the "upper triangle" or "lower triange":

```
triu = df.pivot(index='row', columns='col', values='val')

col    A    B    C    D
row                    
A    0.2  0.1  0.9  2.1
B    NaN  1.2  2.3  4.3
C    NaN  NaN  3.4  0.8
D    NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0



tril = df.pivot(index='col', columns='row', values='val')

row    A    B    C    D
col                    
A    0.2  NaN  NaN  NaN
B    0.1  1.2  NaN  NaN
C    0.9  2.3  3.4  NaN
D    2.1  4.3  0.8  1.0
```

And then create the full symmetric matrix:

```
triu.fillna(tril)

col    A    B    C    D
row                    
A    0.2  0.1  0.9  2.1
B    0.1  1.2  2.3  4.3
C    0.9  2.3  3.4  0.8
D    2.1  4.3  0.8  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For the above answer, you can also do `triu.fillna(triu.T)` without using/making `tril`